# How to handle/parse ill-formed html into DOM in java?

Tags: java, html, dom, parsing

I am using NekoHtml. It failed parsing html from sites like mercurynews.com into DOM. Any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered Tag Soup?

http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

Answer (score 3):

Beyond switching to [other parsers](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)? If the site has consistent error patterns, you could hot fix them via series of regex before passing on to the parser.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the Swing HTML parser.

http://www.rkcole.com/articles/swing/HTMLParser.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Cobra renderer from the "Lobo Project" (http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) for parsing less-than-friendly HTML and it has worked well. It's API is also very easy to use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to tidy it before parsing, or better yet use it as the parser

Comment: I find that JTidy is slow and is not maintained since 2000.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "sites like" means, but MercuryNews.com and most news sites have an [RSS interface](http://www.mercurynews.com/rss).

Comment: RSS only provides short snippets on most of the sites. I am interested in parsing the full articles, which are in html format.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried jsoup - http://jsoup.org -.

It is an open source Java library for real-world HTML parsing and DOM manipulation, with jquery-like methods.